# Joda DateTime - range of days in month

Tags: java, jodatime

I use Joda DateTime like this:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(31).withMonthOfYear(10).withYear(2017);
```

and get the following exception:

```
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Value 0 for dayOfMonth must be in the range [1,30]
```

but I dont know why - oct always has 31 days?

Comment: This seems to be that November has 30 days?

Comment: new DateTime() is now. Now is November, not October.

Comment: ok, sry, First I have to set the month, and afterwards the days, sry and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems DateTime API checks valid days on the basis of month which is inputed. So if you will put month first then it should work fine like this.

> ```
>     DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().withMonthOfYear(10).withDayOfMonth(31).withYear(2017);
> ```